# Adding new field containing file in Laravel registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I wanted to customize the Laravel auth system by adding more fields to it. I wanted the user to upload a few images during registration, and I am not sure on what to add on the `create()` method in RegisterController to add the file name into the database, also the file itself to the public folder.

**RegisterController**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        "address"=> $data['address'],
        "phone"=> $data['phone'],
        "git"=> $data['git'],
        "line"=> $data['line'],
        "dob"=> $data['dob'],
        "score",
        "ktp",
        "cv",
    ]);
}
```

As you can see, I wanted the 'score', 'ktp', and 'cv' fields to be filled with images. So what should I add on it to store them in PHPMyAdmin and in public?

**Form**

```php
<form class="need-validation" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <h3>Team</h3>
    <div class="form-col">
        <div class="form-left">
            <div class=" form-group">
                <!-- Username -->
                <label for="validationDefault01">Username</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                       id="name validationDefault01" placeholder="Username" value="{{ old('name') }}" required
                       autocomplete="name" autofocus>
                @error('name')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                 </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="  form-group">
                <!-- Email -->
                <label for="validationDefault02 inputEmail1">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                       id="email validationDefault02 InputEmail1" placeholder="Email" name="email"
                       value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                @error('email')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right">
            <div class=" form-group">
                <!-- Password -->
                <label for="validationDefault03 inputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror"
                       id="password validationDefault03 inputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="password" required
                       autocomplete="new-password">

                @error('password')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                 </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group">
                <label for="validationDefault04 inputPassword2">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password-confirm validationDefault04 inputPassword2"
                       placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sec">

        <div class=" form-group">
            <!-- Leader Address -->
            <label for="validationDefault07">Address</label>
            <input name="address" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault07" placeholder="Address"
                   required>
        </div>
        <div class=" form-group">
            <!-- Leader Phone Number -->
            <label for="validationDefault08">Phone Number</label>
            <input name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control validationDefault08" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
        </div>
        <div class=" form-group">
            <!-- Leader Git ID -->
            <label for="validationDefault09">Git ID</label>
            <input name="git" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault09" placeholder="Git ID" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-right">
        <div class=" form-group">
            <!-- Leader Line ID -->
            <label for="validationDefault10">Line ID</label>
            <input name="line" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault10" placeholder="Line ID" required>
        </div>
        <div class=" form-group">
            <!-- Leader DOB -->
            <label for="validationDefault11">Date of Birth</label>
            <input name="dob" type="text" class="form-control" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="validationDefault11"
                   placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <!-- Leader Test -->
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input name="score" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01"
                       aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" required>
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Upload your Test Result</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <!-- Leader Test -->
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input name="ktp" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01"
                       aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" required>
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Upload your ID Card</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <!-- Leader Test -->
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input name="cv" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01"
                       aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" required>
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Upload your CV</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

its really easy to add more fields in user table and insert them while user registration don't change your current register controller keep it as is just call registered method and update user table extra fields in that method check Register controller below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

/**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //upload files
        $data = $request->only(['address','phone','git','line','dob','score','ktp','cv']);
        $user->update($data);
        return redirect('send-to-home');
    }
}
```

Note: registered method is part of RegistersUsers trait method it called on user registration.